# Alignment of columns in lsof and ps

Tags: c++, ps, lsof

I was working on parsing the output of `popen` to `lsof` and `ps`.

I was wondering is the first and last column always left aligned? And the rest in between are always right aligned? And as seen in column `FD`, is the minimum width of a column `3`?

For example:

```
COMMAND PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME\n
bash    252 noida  cwd    DIR    1,2      1088 410828 /Users/noida ion/Desktop\n
bash    252 noida  txt    REG    1,2    628736  11647 /bin/bash\n
bash    252 noida  txt    REG    1,2    622896  11866 /usr/lib/dyld\n
bash    252 noida  txt    REG    1,2 382100934 418209 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64\n
bash    252 noida    0u   CHR   16,0  0t401079    601 /dev/ttys000\n
bash    252 noida    1u   CHR   16,0  0t401079    601 /dev/ttys000\n
bash    252 noida    2u   CHR   16,0  0t401079    601 /dev/ttys000\n
bash    252 noida  255u   CHR   16,0  0t401079    601 /dev/ttys000\n
0\u000b\u0001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The out put you are getting is may be a default formatted one.
While passing the shell command in popen add the format options too.

Pipe the column command to your lsof command.

ex:

to reverse the alignment

lsof -ps | column -t | rev

rough example:

//for reversing the allignment.

```
FILE *fp;
char pOpenCmd[100] = "lsof -ps | column -t | rev";
fp = popen(pOpenCmd, "r");
```

for just aligning everything to left side, use "column -t"

may be you can pipe "column -c" to specify width of columns.

You have some more options here in this below link.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html